# Assigning bins to records in CHAID model

Tags: spss-modeler

I built a custom CHAID tree in SPSS modeler.  I would like to assign the particular terminal nodes to all of the records in the dataset.  How would I go about doing this from within the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you used the regular node called CHAID, if you select inside the diamond icon (created chaid model) in the tab configurations the rule identifyer, the output will add another variable called $RI-XXX that will classify all the records within the terminal nodes. Just check that option and then put a table node after that and all the records will be classified.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the algorithm to whatever data set you need, and you only need to inputs to be the same (type and eventually storage).
The diamond contains the algo and you can disconnect it and connects to whatever you want.

http://beyondthearc.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/spss.png